# Click event on element directly

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

I have a trouble with click events on ios safari. When i `click` on the span nothing happens first time. But when i focus on span its selected then after click events working. Can somebody explain this weird event ? or any suggestion ?
Here is my javascript:

```
window.selectText = function() {
    $('.banks .number').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).select();

        var doc = document,
            text = this,
            range,
            selection;

        if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
            range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(text);
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            selection = window.getSelection();
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(text);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }    
    });
}
```

And html snippet:

```
<div class="banks">
    <div class="bank-title">Хүлээн авагчийн данс</div>
    <div class="bank khaan">
        <div class="spacer" id="test">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <span class="number">5037639120</span>
            <span class="name">Хаан банк</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bank khas">
        <div class="spacer">
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <span class="number">5002086050</span>
            <span class="name">Хас банк</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my goal is when users click on `span.number` its must select the texts. But i don't understand why click event not works on first click and after focusing span its selected then other click events works.

Comment: I had some click issues on safari before but I am not sure if it's the same case as yours. You have to add this css to your spans `cursor: pointer`

Comment: Well your event listener will only be added once `selectText()` is called. When do you call that function?

Comment: @PatrickEvans when i open form and to click a button and that `divs` appear its dynamically added into form. And i call a function when users click show bank accounts then i call my function.

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien its not works :)

Comment: Well, adding to what @PatrickEvans said you have to add the click event before `selectText()` is called or pass the clicked element to it like `selectText(element)` and remove/unwrap the click event from the function and replace `this` with `element`. Like `window.selectText = function(element) {$(element).select(); /*The rest of the code*/}`

Comment: When i trying what you said it gives me these error
`Failed to execute 'selectNodeContents' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`

Comment: I call it like `<span onclick="selectText(this);" >text</span>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
          
            jQuery(".banks").click(function () {
               
                jQuery(".number").click(function (e) {
                    var se = window.getSelection();
                    alert(se);
                    //your logic can apply here
                    exit();
                });
                
            });
           
           
        });
```